# How to add a textview in Uiscrollview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

Using storyboard i want to add `UITextview` in the `UIScrollview` and the scroll the TextView in the in the screen. please help me...

```
scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,846); 
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES]; 
int GetIndex = [GetSelectedIndex intValue]; 
label = [firstheading objectAtIndex:GetIndex]; 
labelheading.text=label; 
textviews = [firstdesc objectAtIndex:GetIndex];
textview.text=textviews; 
[scroller addSubview:textview]; 
NSLog(@"textview:%@",textview);
 NSLog(@"image:%@",getimage);
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your problem with that? It should work straight away.

Comment: However, do not enalbe scrolling on the textview. I don't know why but it drove me crazy the other day. I did not get it working. In the event that you do not want to enalbe editing then I advise to use a multiline lable instead of a text view.

Comment: In my app i add label, imageview  and textview to the UIscrollview if darg to scroll a it will not scroll

Comment: ok i will try using label for the textview

Comment: Make sure that the UITextView (or what ever you use) is a proper subview of the UIScrollView. Are you using IB or do you do that programmatically? If so, please share some relevant code.

Comment: scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,846);
     [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    int GetIndex = [GetSelectedIndex intValue];
    
    
    label = [firstheading objectAtIndex:GetIndex];
    labelheading.text=label;
    
    textviews = [firstdesc objectAtIndex:GetIndex];
    textview.text=textviews;
    [scroller addSubview:textview];
    
    NSLog(@"textview:%@",textview);
    
    NSLog(@"image:%@",getimage);

Comment: OK, I added the code to the question. Please review and approve the edit. Code in comments is nearly unreadable.

Comment: What is the frame of that text view? Where/how is it created and initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, you could try adding a UIView on your ViewController first.
Then drag the UIScrollView into your UIView.
Then drag a UITextView into that.

I have this arrangement in a Storyboard - because I have an image in the top level UIView as well as the UIScrollView